# Why is the list not rendering?

Tags: reactjs

i'm new to react and i'm playing around to see how the basic concepts work. I'm trying to render at list with data from a firebase server, the deta gets fetched ok but i'm having trouble rendering it in my listitem component.

Parent Component:

```js
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: null as null | Data[]
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  private getData(): void {
    let _data = new Array < Data > ()
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection('data').get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
          let data: Data = {
            id: doc.id,
            name: doc.data().name,
            description: doc.data().description,
            country: doc.data().country,
            town: doc.data().town,
            lat: doc.data().lat,
            long: doc.data().long,
            created: doc.data().created,
            updated: doc.data().updated,
            img: doc.data().img
          }
          _data.push(data)
        })
      })
    this.setState({
      data: _data
    })
  }



  render() {
    let list = null;
    if (this.state.data) {
      list = ( 
      <div > {
          this.state.data.map(d => {
            return <ListObject name = {d.name} />
          })
        } </div>
      )
    }
    return ( 
      <div>
        <p> List </p>
        {list}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Child Component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import './ListObject.css';

const listObject = (props: any) => {
    return (
        <div className="ListObject">
            <p>i Am {props.name}</p>
        </div>
    )
};

export default listObject;
```

What am i doing wrong here? The ListObject component works outside of the iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `db.collection('data').get()` asynchronously run so that in your code, state haven't been set:

```
let _data = [];
db.collection('data').get().then(function() {
   _data.append();
});
this.setState({
    data: _data
})
```

there is no data in `_data`.

So to get rid of this, you could use synchronous loop `for ... of`, and make the code a bit easier to read like so:

```
private getData(): void {
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    db.collection('data').get()
      .then(snapshot => {
         let _data = new Array < Data > ()
         for (let doc of snapshot.docs) {
            let data: Data = {
                id: doc.id,
                name: doc.data().name,
                description: doc.data().description,
                country: doc.data().country,
                town: doc.data().town,
                lat: doc.data().lat,
                long: doc.data().long,
                created: doc.data().created,
                updated: doc.data().updated,
                img: doc.data().img
            }
            _data.push(data);
         }
         this.setState({
             data: _data
         });
      })
  }
```

and your render:

```
render() {
    let list = (this.state.data || []).map(d => {
        return <ListObject name = {d.name} />
    });

    return ( 
        <div>
            <p> List </p>
            <div>{list}</div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: yeah sorry the dogparks was a typo that i have fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. it's supposed to be inside render function.

Answer (score 1):

Because `dogparks` is null.

Also you should create `list` outside of your render method.

So like:

```
let list = (this.state.data || []).map(d => {
    return <ListObject name = {d.name} />
});

render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <p> List </p>
        <div>{list}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```